# Continuity of Lagrange multipliers

Tags: real-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose I have an optimization problem of the from $\min f(x)$, s.t. $g(x)=a$, where $f,g$ are real polynomials and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Then using the Lagrange multiplier rule, I have to find the critical points of the Lagrange function $\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda):=f(x)+\lambda\cdot (g(x)-a)$. Now if I have solved this system and I consider a system that is slightly perturbed, i.e. I replace $f,g$ by $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ which I define as $\tilde{f}_\epsilon:=f+\epsilon\cdot p_1$ and $\tilde{g}_\epsilon:=g+\epsilon\cdot p_2$, where $p_1,p_2$ are fixed polynomials.  What can be said about the dependency of the Langrange multipliers of this system on $\epsilon$? Are they also depending continuously an this perturbation?

Comment: $g$ must be somehow linked to $f$.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: What on earth do you mean?

Comment: I say that in its current for your question makes no sense.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: Again: What on earth do you mean? This is a perfectly good question.

Comment: A continuous perturbation may be non-differentiable, so I agree with @SeyhmusGüngören, this question makes no sense.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Not necessarily so. If the perturbation is of the form $\tilde{f}(x) = f(x) + p(\epsilon)h(x)$, then $h$ has to be differentiable, but $p$ doesn't.